# How to create CSV string from String Array, If string is blank at any index than just discard it

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Let's say I have array like {"12","23","","34","22","","","12"}

If there are 5 items as than it should append "`<br/>` after 2 items.
I want to arrange this in string like "12,23,`</br>`34,22`</br>`,12";

If there are 3 items in array string should break after 2 items.

There will be max 7 items in array.

Comment: I've read your "question" 3 times and I still have no idea what you really want...

Comment: Do we really need `rearrange` and `arrange-items` tags on SO?!

Comment: What language do you want to do this in? When you say you have an "array", is this a list of values in CSV or an actual array of items in your language of choice?

Comment: I have say 9 items in array, I want to show it in html with line break exactly after 2 items, if there's blank item than it should discard. So that I can show it properly on my presentation layer. Let me know if you still require explanation.

Comment: @Adam : while posting question I found this tags, appropriate, that's the reason to put it in that category

Comment: @ashish: You didn't answer the question about what language this is to be in, and you didn't answer the question about what an "array" is in this context.

Comment: @Adam: Target language is C# and "array" means I have list of data in string array. From that I want to generate comma separated string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourArray = ...;
yourArray = yourArray.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSPace(str)).ToArray();

var yourResult = Enumerate
  .Range(0, yourArray.Length)
  .Select(index => (index % 3 == 0)?("<br>" + yourArray[index]):yourArray[index])
  .Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex);
```

change Aggregate to ToList().ForEach(...stringbuilder.Append ) for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Is this (pseudo-code) something like what you want? I believe your goal is to collapse multiple empty elements into a single `<br/>` element; if that is not accurate, please try to clarify your intention.

```
sb = new stringBuilder
justWroteBr = false
foreach s in array
    if s == ""
        if justWroteBr
            continue
        else
            s.Add("<br/>")
            justWroteBr = true
        end
    else
        s.Add(s + ",")
        justWroteBr = false
    end
next
```